# GWT image centered over the application

Tags: java, gwt

I'm wondering about how it works to center an image over the hole GWT application 
when pressing a button and make it disappear when a special position in the 
code is reached.

It will be a `"waiting.gif"` that shows a circle spinning around while the program
is calculating something. When the result is calculated the GIF should disappear.

Do i have to do it with some kind of pop-up-panel? or how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following options

**1)** What do you want is a loading mask.. For that you can use [Image Loading Cell](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ImageLoadingCell.java?r=10797/ImageLoadingCell.java) provided by the gwt or If you are making an **Async** call then you may probably try out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309436/automatic-loading-indicator-when-calling-an-async-function)

**2)** You can add a stylename for your application, and in the css, use the image whichever you want, set a low **opacity** property.

**Avoid using Popups as calculating the exact postion of the images may be cumbersome**